# PdfDocument remains locked after closing

Tags: c#, .net, itext7

I have a windows service which merges PDFs together on the fly and then moves them to another location.  I don't have control over what someone wants merged, for the most part.  It has happened that every so often a corrupted PDF gets processed and therefore creating the new PdfDocument throws a PdfException "Trailer not found".  I am catching the exception and closing the document but it appears after closing the PDF itself is still locked somehow.  I need to delete the directory but in trying to do that it throws an IOException and crashes the service.

I have verified that calling the PdfDocument constructor is what locks the pdf and that immediately after closing the file remains locked.

Any ideas?  Is there something iText can do to help with is or do I need to come up with some sort of work around where I check for corrupted PDFs up front?

**ProcessDirectory**

---

```
    private void ProcessDirectory(string directoryPath)
    {
        EventLogManager.WriteInformation("ProcessDirectory");
        // DON'T TOUCH THE BACKUPS, ERRORS AND WORK DIRECTORIES.  Just in case they were made or renamed after the fact for some reason
        if (directoryPath != this._errorsPath && directoryPath != this._backupsPath && directoryPath != this._workPath)
        {
            string pdfJsonPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(directoryPath, "pdf.json");

            if (File.Exists(pdfJsonPath))
            {
                string workPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(this._workPath, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(directoryPath));

                try
                {
                    CopyToDirectory(directoryPath, workPath);

                    PdfMerge pdfMerge = null;

                    string jsonPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(workPath, "pdf.json");
                    using (StreamReader r = Helpers.GetStreamReader(jsonPath))
                    {
                        string json = r.ReadToEnd();
                        pdfMerge = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PdfMerge>(json);
                    }

                    FillFormFields(workPath, pdfMerge);

                    if (pdfMerge.Pdfs.Any(p => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.OverlayFilename)))
                    {
                        ApplyOverlays(workPath, pdfMerge);
                    }

                    MergePdfs(workPath, pdfMerge);
                    //NumberPages(workPath, pdfMerge);
                    FinishPdf(workPath, pdfMerge);

                    // Move original to backups directory
                    if (DoSaveBackups)
                    {
                        string backupsPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(this._backupsPath, String.Format("{0}_{1}", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(directoryPath), DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")));
                        Directory.Move(directoryPath, backupsPath);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Directory.Delete(directoryPath, true);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    EventLogManager.WriteError(ex);

                    if (DoSaveErrors)
                    {
                        // Move original to errors directory
                        string errorsPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(this._errorsPath, String.Format("{0}_{1}", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(directoryPath), DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")));
                        Directory.Move(directoryPath, errorsPath);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Directory.Delete(directoryPath, true);
                    }
                }

                // Delete work directory
                // THIS IS WHERE THE IOEXCEPTION OCCURS AND THE SERVICE CRASHES
                Directory.Delete(workPath, true);
            }
            else
            {
                EventLogManager.WriteInformation(String.Format("No pdf.json file.  {0} skipped.", directoryPath));
            }
        }
    }
```

**FillFormFields**

---

```
    private void FillFormFields(string directoryPath, PdfMerge pdfMerge)
    {
        if (pdfMerge != null && pdfMerge.Pdfs != null)
        {
            string formPath = String.Empty;
            string newFilePath;
            PdfDocument document = null;
            PdfAcroForm form;
            PdfFormField pdfFormField;

            foreach (var pdf in pdfMerge.Pdfs)
            {
                try
                {
                    formPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(directoryPath, pdf.Filename);
                    newFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(
                        directoryPath,
                        String.Format("{0}{1}", String.Format("{0}{1}", System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pdf.Filename), "_Revised"), System.IO.Path.GetExtension(pdf.Filename)));

                    // THIS IS WHERE THE PDFEXCEPTOIN OCCURS
                    document = new PdfDocument(Helpers.GetPdfReader(formPath), new PdfWriter(newFilePath));
                    form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(document, true);

                    if (pdf.Fields != null && pdf.Fields.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (var field in pdf.Fields)
                        {
                            if (field.Value != null)
                            {
                                pdfFormField = form.GetField(field.Name);

                                if (pdfFormField != null)
                                {
                                    form.GetField(field.Name).SetValue(field.Value);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    EventLogManager.WriteWarning(String.Format("Field '{0}' does not exist in '{1}'", field.Name, pdf.Filename));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    form.FlattenFields();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception(String.Format("An exception occurred filling form fields for {0}", pdf.Filename), ex);
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (document != null)
                    {
                        document.Close();
                    }
                }

                // Now rename the new one back to the old name
                File.Delete(formPath);
                File.Move(newFilePath, formPath);
            }
        }
    }
```

### UPDATE

It seems in order to everything to dispose properly you have to declare separate PdfReader and PdfWriter objects into using statements and pass those into the PdfDocument.  Like this:

```
    using (reader = Helpers.GetPdfReader(formPath))
    {
        using (writer = new PdfWriter(newFilePath))
        {
            using (document = new PdfDocument(reader, writer))
            {
                // The rest of the code here
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure why this is other than that iText isn't disposing of the individual PdfReader and PdfWriter when disposing of the PdfDocument, which I assumed it would.

Comment: you need to dispose of the following objects, 
PdfDocument document = null;
            PdfAcroForm form;
            PdfFormField pdfFormField; I would make them public objects of the class out side of the method and make sure you set them to null when complete.. the GC probably has not cleaned up the resources after you closed the pdf. if they implement IDisposible then you could do some thing like this 
`((IDisposible)PdfAcroForm).Dispose();` for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find out which of the itext7 classes implement IDisposable (from the documentation, or the Visual Studio Object Browser etc), and make sure you use them within using blocks, the same way you already have using blocks for StreamReader.

Edit: @sourkrause's solution can be shortened to:

```
using (reader = Helpers.GetPdfReader(formPath))
using (writer = new PdfWriter(newFilePath))
using (document = new PdfDocument(reader, writer))
{
    // The rest of the code here
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was what I needed.  It wasn't good enough, however, to wrap PdfDocument in a using statement.  I had to declare individual PdfReader and PdfWriter objects as well and have using statements for all 3 in order to everything to dispose properly.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but this is my approach to solving in iText7, and it is quite different then the accepted answer. Since I could not use using statements, I took a different approach when closing out the document. This may seem like over kill, but it works very well.

First I closed the Document:

```
Document.Close();
```

Nothing out of the ordinary here.. after doing this however, I close / dispose the Reader and Writer instances. After closing them out, I'll set the writer, reader, and document in that order to null. The GC should take care of clearing these up, but for my usage the object that was holding these instance is still being used, so to free up some memory I'm doing this additional step.

step 2

```
Writer.Close();
Writer.Dispose();
Writer = null;
```

Step 3

```
Reader.SetCloseStream(true);
Reader.Close();
Reader = null;
```

Step 4

```
Document = null;
```

I would suggest you wrap each step in a try catch; depending on how your code is running, you could see issues doing this all at once.

I believe the most important part here is the actions taken on the reader. For some reason, the reader does not seem to close the stream when calling .Close() by default.

***While running in production I have still noticed that one file (so far anyways) still held a lock when trying to delete right after closing. I added a catch that waits a few seconds before trying again. That seems to do the trick on those more "stubborn" files.